# Configuring the Spring Batch infrastructure in a database - MySQL Data Truncation Error

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have implemented Spring Batch job repository implementation to store the job metadata in a
database.

**Configuration of a persistent job repository**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in memory --> 

    <batch:job-repository id="jobRepository"
    data-source="dataSource"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

database.xml is as folows :-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <!-- connect to database -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sod_sustenance" />
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@internal.com:1533:vis" />
        <property name="username" value="system"></property>
        <property name="password" value="manager"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" /> -->

    <!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>


</beans>
```

after i run the Application , the tables are created in MySQL.
However i get the following error :-

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATE_TIME' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATE_TIME' at row 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:872)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.saveJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:155)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:124)
    at com.sodconflict.App.run(App.java:43)
    at com.sodconflict.App.main(App.java:24)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATE_TIME' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:681)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1368)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 21 more
```

Due to this error, the values could not be inserted and the jobs metadata are not inserted.

**Just an Update**  -  The following table structure is created in MySQL :-

```
CREATE TABLE `batch_job_execution` (
  `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `VERSION` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `JOB_INSTANCE_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CREATE_TIME` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `START_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `END_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXIT_CODE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXIT_MESSAGE` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JOB_EXECUTION_ID`),
  KEY `JOB_INST_EXEC_FK` (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `JOB_INST_EXEC_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID`) REFERENCES `batch_job_instance` (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Might be unrelated but shouldn't the type for CREATE_TIME be dateTime instead of date?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this JDBC option:

```
jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
```

[More info here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

Comment: I tried setting jdbcCompliantTruncation = false. Now its not showing me the truncation error and the values got inserted in the tables.However now i am getting the exception as :-  Exit Status : [org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly].Do you have any idea , how shall i debug it.

Comment: No idea sorry, you need to provide the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Oracle as job-repo metadata holder and check if it works? Because, as described in [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?137235) thread, can be an issue with My SQL connector driver.

Comment: Might be possible it works in Oracle,but is their any workaround in MySQL

Comment: Maybe changing mysql driver or mysql version, if is possible

Comment: hi @bellabax, setting jdbcCompliantTruncation = false removes the truncation error now , however now i am getting `org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly` exception

Comment: have the full stack trace will help :)